# Blender 4.0 Remesh creates a blocky look with an unusual topology

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, remesh

I am creating a basic human within Blender version 4.0. I have never came across this situation before.
I added cubes, used a subdivision modifiers up to 3. then applied once I got the shape I wanted. After I proceeded to apply a remesh to the body which worked great as I applied voxel size of 0.04m. I smoothed down the surface and everything was going wonders. The head I did not attach to the body nor the hands as I was working on the body, legs, and arms as a whole first before getting to the smaller details.

When I had gone to the hand part, I remeshed it down to 0.01m and it looked like almost non existing. I applied a much smaller voxel size of 0.01m and it still did not work. When I went into *Edit Mode*, the topology was looking as if I grabbed a cube and extruded it only one time. In order for it to work I had to use voxel size of 0.001m but it was way too much to handle. I can't remesh the head now, nor the body again. It just wants me to use a low voxel size of 0.001m. I did not add any other modifiers other than the mirror tool, and subdivision. Also I did a shade smooth to the body.
I tried looking around but found nothing like this. I tried adding in another cube, sub-divide it to 3, applied, and remeshed it and that worked. I used that same cube to make of the hand using the way of shaping the cube to fit the hand, then applying the subdivision, then using the sculpt tool to get the size I want. When I apply the remesh tool, it is doing the same thing.
Hopefully this was specific enough to understand, but I don't know what could have gone wrong, I never had this problem. I could go and create another sculpt but I don't wanna get to that point where it happens again. I'm hoping I can fix this within the settings or within the mesh but I tried and I am now left stuck with where I'm at.

On the pictures provided you can see before using remesh and after. When using a lower remesh, it gets a bit better but impossible to sculpt on, I don't think I should even go that low (below voxel size 0.01m). The only way I can sculpt out my hand is when I remesh it to voxel size 0.001m but again it is too much and it isn't the best to sculpt. This is the same when applying a remesh modifier and going into sculpt mode to remesh it. It's the exact same results.

[image: How the hand is originally]

[image: A lower voxel size]